# Swift error while do action

Tags: swift, xcode, if-statement, swift3

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee3387ff8)

Can any correct it if wrong? I think the problem comes from `else if` statement {} < if can any one fix it and tell me where is the problem in the previous code I posted and what i have  to do to solve the problem I don't know if some can help me?

```
func fetchAndUpdateTableView(){
    if catagory == "Tools" {
        if let url = urlCoreData{
            switch (url) {
        case "All_m0":
            let shit = All_m0()
            coreVariables.results_All_M0 = shit.fetchProduct()!
            break
        case "Screw_drive":
            let  screwd = Screw_drive()
            coreVariables.results_Screw_Drive = screwd.fetchProduct()!
            break
        case "Wrench_m":
            let Wrenchm = Wrench_m()
            coreVariables.results_Wrench_M = Wrenchm.fetchProduct()!
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        }

        else if catagory == "Water Pressure"{
            if let url = urlCoreData{
                switch (url) {
                case "All_m1":
                    let All1 = All_m1()
                    coreVariables.results_All_M1 = All1.fetchProduct()!
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }

        }



        else if catagory == "Garden Equipments"{

            if let url = urlCoreData{
                switch (url) {
                case "All_m2":
                    let All2 = All_m2()
                    coreVariables.results_All_M2 = All2.fetchProduct()!
                    break
                default:
                    break


        }
            }


        }
   tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
}

//MARK: get and parse JSON

func processJsonData(resource : String) {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: resource, ofType: "json")
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!), options: .alwaysMapped)
        do{
            let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: .allowFragments)
            if let dictionary = object as? NSArray {
                fetch_Store_Functions.readJSONObject(object: dictionary, catagory: catagory, urlCoreData: urlCoreData)
            }
        } catch {
            // Handle Error
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func loadFunction(){
    if catagory == "Tools" {
        if let url = urlCoreData{
            switch (url) {
        case "All_m0":
          //  self.fetchAndUpdateTableView()
            if coreVariables.results_All_M0.count == 0{
                self.processJsonData(resource: selectedCatagory)
            }else{
                self.fetchAndUpdateTableView()
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
            break
        case "Screw_drive":
        //self.fetchAndUpdateTableView()
            if coreVariables.results_Screw_Drive.count == 0{
                self.processJsonData(resource: selectedCatagory)
                tableView.reloadData()
            }else{
                self.fetchAndUpdateTableView()
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
            break
        case "Wrench_m":
           // self.fetchAndUpdateTableView()
            if coreVariables.results_Wrench_M.count == 0{
                self.processJsonData(resource: selectedCatagory)
                tableView.reloadData()
            }else{
                self.fetchAndUpdateTableView()
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        }
    }else if catagory == "Water Pressure"{
            if let url = urlCoreData{
                switch (url) {
            case "All_m1":
                self.fetchAndUpdateTableView()
                if coreVariables.results_All_M1.count == 0{
                    self.processJsonData(resource: selectedCatagory)
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }else{
                    self.fetchAndUpdateTableView()
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
                break
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
    }else if catagory == "Garden Equipments"{
        if let url = urlCoreData{
            switch (url) {
            case "All_m2":
                //  self.fetchAndUpdateTableView()
                if coreVariables.results_All_M2.count == 0{
                    self.processJsonData(resource: selectedCatagory)
                }else{
                    self.fetchAndUpdateTableView()
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
                break
            default:
                break


        }
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Any carelessly written exclamation mark (`!`) can crash the app. And please read again my answer to your previous question: **No `break` statements in `switch` cases (except `default`)** and **no *snake_cased* variable names** in Swift.

Comment: plz can u do one example to understand

Comment: I don't understand because I am beginning

Comment: Obviously `fetchProduct()` returns an optional. Force unwrapping (`!`) an optional causes a crash if the optional is `nil`. Please read the Swift Language Guide about optionals. And if you are a beginner please take advices about syntax and naming convention.

Comment: ok I will try to fix it

Comment: in `fetchAndUpdateTableView()` the category if conditions are nested , try to end `if category == "Tools"` condition before `else if category == "Water Pressure"` condition and end `else if category == "Water Pressure"` condition before `else if category == "Garden Equipments"` condition

Comment: still not working

Comment: done its work by anther var

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in Zombie Objects in your scheme, then go into profile instruments, Zombies and run the app and see if it catches it like this.

This error occurs when there has been memory allocated to a variable and then it is released and then another process tries to use that variable.